# How to allow horizontal overflowing in a richtextbox control in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, richtextbox

I'm Working on an application that uses RichTextbox to display and edit text. The Problem is, if a line will gets longer than the textbox's width it will breaks up to the next line.

How can I allow user to enter long lines into the Rich Textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wordwrap-property does this, you can disable it in the property window of your property or using:

```
RichTextBox1.WordWrap = False
```